# if else inside for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I came across this post about an ifelse statement inside a for loop:

[How to create new variables using loop and ifelse statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190986/how-to-create-new-variables-using-loop-and-ifelse-statement)

```
var1 <- c(0,0,1,2)
var2 <- c(2,2,2,0)
var3 <- c(0,0,0,2)
var4 <- c(1,2,2,2)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4))
df

 var1 var2 var3 var4 
   0    2    0    1   
   0    2    0    2   
   1    2    0    2   
   2    0    2    2
```

Based on the post the output would be:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 new
   0    2    0    1   1
   0    2    0    2   0
   1    2    0    2   1
   2    0    2    2   0
```

Because if in any element in one row there is 1 the corresponding row in the column (new) will be 1 else it will be 0

I wrote something like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(mean(df[i,] == 1) == 0){
    df$new[i]<- 0}
  else{
    df$new[i]<- 1    
  }}
```

However, it is giving this output:

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 new
 0    2    0    1   1
 0    2    0    2   1
 1    2    0    2   1
 2    0    2    2   1
```

if I modify the code if(mean(df[i,] == 1) == 0) to if(mean(df[i] == 1) == 0) then it works, but in another cases, if I modify the data frame by including 1 at certain position then if(mean(df[i,] == 1) == 0) is correct and not if(mean(df[i] == 1) == 0).

Can anybody explain this behavior? and how can my loop could be modified to be correct all the times?
Any explanation highly appreciated!

Comment: does not seems to do anything, still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized solution is always better:

```
df$new <- as.integer(rowSums(df == 1) > 0)
```

As for your code, I think it works. It's likely that while you were testing, you still had `df$new` in your dataframe which caused the logic to mess up. I can't reproduce the error.

```
var1 <- c(0,0,1,2)
var2 <- c(2,2,2,0)
var3 <- c(0,0,0,2)
var4 <- c(1,2,2,2)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4))

df2 <- df
df2
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    0    2    0    1
2    0    2    0    2
3    1    2    0    2
4    2    0    2    2

df2$new <- as.integer(rowSums(df == 1) > 0)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(mean(df[i,] == 1) == 0){
    df2$new[i]<- 0}
  else{
    df2$new[i]<- 1    
  }}

df2

  var1 var2 var3 var4 new
1    0    2    0    1   1
2    0    2    0    2   0
3    1    2    0    2   1
4    2    0    2    2   0
```

Comment: hmm..I think what you are saying it is very correct, I restarted R and clear the environment all the time, now it seems to be ok, in fact, I had the impression that the code should correct right?...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data provided

```
var1 <- c(0,0,1,2)
var2 <- c(2,2,2,0)
var3 <- c(0,0,0,2)
var4 <- c(1,2,2,2)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4))

get_1 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c(1)))

vec = c()

for (i in get_1){ 
    if(i == 'TRUE'){
        vec <- c(vec, 1)
    }
    else if(i == 'FALSE'){
        vec <- c(vec, 0)
    }
}

df$new <- vec
df

#OUTPUT

#    var1 var2 var3 var4 new
#     0   2    0    1     1
#     0   2    0    2     0
#     1   2    0    2     1
#     2   0    2    2     0
```

Comment: thank you, yes, your solution is ok but I was also looking for an explanation about why my loop does not work according to what I was expecting...how to loop over each element of each row?